# What Was the Name of the High Tech TV Spy Show in the 70's?

Tags: story-identification

I remember a show from the 1970s where agents had miniature cameras (rings and pendants) and 2-way communications with a command center staffed by translators and other specialists who communicated with them in real time.  Does anyone know what the title of this show was?

Answer (score 7):

I believe it was [*Search*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_%28TV_series%29).  It was based on a movie called [*Probe*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probe_(1972_TV_pilot)) and involved a high tech private investigation firm.  It aired in 1972 and 1973.

> *Probe* was a two-hour television film first aired on February 21, 1972 on NBC as pilot for a science fiction detective series, originally to have continued under that title. Created by Leslie Stevens, it starred Hugh O'Brian as Hugh Lockwood, one of a group of high-tech private eyes working for the organization “World Securities”. When picked up for series production, the title was changed to *Search*, because *Probe* was the name of an existing PBS series.
>
> The investigators, called Probes, were outfitted with various electronic implants including **a button-sized "scanner" containing a miniaturized video camera, microphone and transmitter linked to a team of technicians and experts** who constantly monitored the Probe's surroundings, actions and vital signs; they were able to supply the Probe with encyclopedic information on any subject.

Comment: This answer features the only good clue: pendant or jewelry hiding cameras.

Comment: @GorchestopherH: I think there's a reason for so few good clues.  I don't think the series was repeated, so many of us may remember it, but not well because it was a long time ago.  Also, the real-time communication is a good clue, too.

Comment: FYI, Wikipedia has a nice image of the lead actors: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probe_(1972_TV_pilot)#mediaviewer/File:WSHQ.jpg

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield: Yeah - I need to add the link to the _Probe_ article to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

- Get Smart Ended in 1970

  - Get Smart is a comedy series that satirizes the secret agent genre that aired on both NBC and CBS from 1965 to 1970. Created by Mel Brooks with Buck Henry, the show starred Don Adams (as Maxwell Smart, Agent 86), Barbara Feldon (as Agent 99), and Edward Platt (as Chief).
- Mission: Impossible also ran through the 1970's

  - Mission: Impossible aired on CBS from September 1966 to March 1973 and chronicled the adventures of the Impossible Missions Force (IMF), a team of government spies and specialists who were offered "impossible missions" (should they decide to accept them) by the unseen "Secretary".

these are the only shows listed on [Classic TV's website](http://www.classic-tv.com/70s-shows) that have an agent type of character in them that are Sci-Fi in nature and these both spanned both the '60's and '70's

Answer (score 3):

It's a 60's show, but perhaps what you're looking for is [The Man from U.N.C.L.E](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Man_from_U.N.C.L.E.)?

[image: Logo]

[image: Main Cast]